# Looking for free cloud picture server

Tags: java, web, cloud, hosting, vuforia

I'm want to get an Image from the cloud like this example:

```
URL url = new URL("https://developer.vuforia.com/samples/cloudreco /json/samplebook1.json");
URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 128);
baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(128);`
```

Do you know a free cloud server that can let me store my Images ?
Need some help please.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what your asking for is an image hosting site, maybe http://www.imgur.com ?

If this is not correct, please explain your question in more detail, a code sample of downloading an image does not offer much in site into a solution your looking for

Comment: No I want to have something like this: https://developer.vuforia.com/samples/cloudreco/thumbs/01_thumbnail.png

Comment: @MoctarHaiz ... you sent me a link to an image, I have no idea what this is suppose to mean. Google image search has many images if thats what your looking for ...

Comment: Sorry for my explanation. I don't speak english very well. I wonder if there is an image cloud server wich allow to store an image an to get it like in the former link.

Comment: @MoctarHaiz ... and ? ... are you going to try again or just leave it at that? it sounds like your looking for an image hosting website as I mentioned above. If that is not what your looking for (Please look at the link before saying no), please explain what it is you want and I may be able to help, sending me to a link is not an example of what your looking for

Comment: I want to use the getInputStream() in java to get my own single image from an URL like in this example: URL url = new URL("https://developer.vuforia.com/samples/cloudreco/thumbs/01_thumbnail.png");
URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 128);
baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(128);`

Comment: @MoctarHaiz yes you've said that, more than once. I understand you want to use this code, its very nice code, id like to use it too. What is it about this code that you need our help with ? A "cloud picture server" is not anything i've heard of before, as i've said again and again it sounds like and image hosting site, where you send your images and you are given a like to access them, like the one I have mentioned above!!! If this is not correct please, use words and tell me why this is not right and what it doesn't do that you need it to

Comment: THANK you very much, it works fine. I haven't click on the image once i've upload it to get the link. thank you again

Comment: @MoctarHaiz ok, don't forget to upvote and mark my answer as top answer so I get the rep points and others with the same issue will know what solved your problem

Comment: I marked it but i can't upvote it cause I haven't the min reputation :p

Answer (score 1):

A good place to store your images on the cloud is Amazon S3. However, you can always use other providers like Dropbox (which works under Amazon S3, as far as I know) or even Google Drive. [This](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat7-hibernate-s3-clickstart) is an application example on GitHub, which upload/download an image to Amazon S3. As you can see, you have the option of deploying it instantly to a specific provider, but you can also use it locally as it is a simple java web application.